# Quarkus for both a cloud and a standalone environment

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to migrate from a classic monolithic JavaEE application (Wildlfy, DB, JMS etc..) to a cloud one using Quarkus. I'm dividing the application into services, that are interacting with each other through REST APIs. So far so good.

My problem is that I still need to support a standalone installation.
I did find a way to build the app as a whole: all services are modules of the same application and the communication is done through beans and not through REST calls. Using profiles at compile time I can decide whether to build a series of services or a single application.

Everything seems to work, but I was wondering if it's a misusage of Quarkus. Should I try another approach? Has anyone had a similar requirement?

Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to understand "Quarkus has been designed with microservices in mind" as "Quarkus is ONLY made for microservices".

Everything that makes Quarkus good for microservices (fast boot, observability, tiny memory footprint) is also good when developing good old monolith apps and it's a perfectly valid use case if microservices are not the right fit for you.

So it's really not a misusage of Quarkus, it's a perfectly valid use case and Quarkus works well for it too.